# DTDL - How to model an elevator room and its movement between levels in Azure Digital Twins?

Tags: azure, azure-digital-twins

I'm using DTDL models defined according to the [RealEstateCore ontology](https://github.com/Azure/opendigitaltwins-building/). I would like to be able to add data which describes on which level an [`ElevatorRoom`](https://github.com/Azure/opendigitaltwins-building/blob/master/Ontology/Space/Room/ElevatorRoom.json) twin is located in the building. The current model does not contain that information nor does the `Room` and `Space` models from where the `ElevatorRoom` is extended.

My question is that what is the best way to define the level information? This data is typically updated frequently as elevators move between levels. I can see at least two alternatives which I'm considering:

1. Current `ElevatorRoom` is extended and **new levelId property is added** to the extended model. *levelId* could be a level number or correspond to a specific Level twin id.
2. **Use RelationShip** to define where `ElevatorRoom` is located. For example, `ElevatorRoom` has `isPartOf` and `isLocationOf` relationships which could be used to link it to a certain [`Level`](https://github.com/Azure/opendigitaltwins-building/blob/master/Ontology/Space/Level.json) twin object corresponding the level where the elevator currently is.

So which one do you recommend to use or is there even better way than options 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1):

I think your misinterpreted the ontology - the `ElevatorRoom` certainly isn't moving.

In my understanding  the `Elevator` is moving in an `ElevatorShaft`, and as an `asset` it already has a `locatedIn` - Relation to spaces e.g. a `Level`. The `ElevatorRoom` is probably the maintenance room for the elevator.

You could model it so that the elevator has two `locatedIn`-Relations, one to the level and one to the elevator shaft. Alternatively there is also a `serves`-Relation you could use like this `Elevator -serves-> ElevatorShaft` and `Elevator -locatedIn->Level`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You are right about the `ElevatorRoom`. It was my misinterpretation and `Elevator` is indeed the correct model. 

Still the main question is open, i.e. which option to use for location: a new property or Relation. You answer is a good one and I'm hoping others to confirm this. Especially those who has actually used this in some real environment.